# How to send automated FCM Notification to android App

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

Iam Building an Android App that can recive FCM notification from Cloud Messaging Console based on Topics(Which i have to do manually).Is there a Way to automate this task?

Comment: Which part of the process you want to automate? You need to add the topic at least once in your code.

Comment: I have done that and notification is showing...just i want to automate that task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is just receiving data, if you want some automation and regular sending you have to implement that on some server side. check out Firebase [DOC](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) for more

if you don't have server-side, only app and above console then you don't have an option for automating push sending. but you can show new `Notification` in some intervals on app-side using scheduled background `Service` (using `JobIntentService`, `AlarmManager`, `WorkManager` etc.), in which you can also do some networking/database check and so on

Comment: Will this "service" able to show notification even if the client app is not connected to internet at the scheduled time?

Comment: yes, it may show `Notification` even offline, but it won't download fresh part of data ofc, when you detect no connectivity you can re-schedule your `Service` again